# Error when using Flutter "list":: Field 'students' should be initialized because its type 'List<Student>' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I'm new to flutter and I ran into a problem while writing on my own computer because my instructor was using an old version.

```
class StudentAdd extends StatefulWidget {
 List<Student> students;
 StudentAdd(List<Student> students){
  this.students=students;
```

> Error: Field 'students' should be initialized because its type
> 'List' doesn't allow null.

I am getting the above error and could not fix it. As far as I looked through the documents, I couldn't find any results.

> **StudentAdd**(List students){

I get an error where I bold it and the error I get is: Non-nullable instance field 'students' must be initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initialize ot as empty list instead of leaving it with null value

```
List<Student> students = <Student>[];
```